# How do I create a type resolver (or a non scalar resolver) using CDK and AppSync?

Tags: graphql, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I am working on a Graph that is hosted on AWS AppSync. The whole project is created and deployed using CDK.

This graph has no type resolvers. All the resolvers are either a Query / Mutation / Subscription resolver. Because of this, every type only has Scalar values. There is nothing more complex. This basically means I have a REST service with a GraphQL interface.

I have searched the internet looking for an examples of people that have done this before me. All of the examples I find are also doing the same thing; returning Scalar values.

I have created a resolver like this

```
  const projectCardResolverFunction = new AppsyncFunction(scope, 'projectCardResolverFunction', {
    name: 'projectCardResolverFunction',
    api,
    dataSource: graphqlDataSource,
    runtime: FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
    code: Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'project-resolver/index.ts')),
  });

  new Resolver(scope, 'projectCardResolver', {
    api,
    typeName: 'Project',
    fieldName: 'card',
    code: Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'project-resolver/passthrough.ts')),
    runtime: FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
    pipelineConfig: [projectCardResolverFunction],
  });
```

Here is the resolver

```
export function request(ctx) {
  console.log('this is the request');
  // return 'This is the request';
  return {
    operation: 'GetItem',
    key: 'this is a test',
  };
}

export function response(ctx) {
  console.log('this is the response');
  return ctx.result;
}
```

And here is the pipeline code

```
// The before step.
// This runs before ALL the AppSync functions in this pipeline.
export function request(ctx) {
  console.log('passthrough request');
  ctx.stash.someValue = 42;
  return {};
}

// The after step.
// This runs after ALL the AppSync functions in this pipeline.
export function response(ctx) {
  console.log('passthrough response');
  return ctx.prev.result;
}
```

I hit the resolver, but I either run into an issue of unknown operation or a bad request / response mapping.

Also, I am required to have a `typeName` and a `fieldName`, so I think this means I have to go through this boiler plate with each field on a type instead of having a single resolver for the whole type.

I am struggling to understand all of this.

1. Does anyone have a working example I can look at of a AWS Amplify / CDK deployed Graph that has types that resolve to something other than a Scalar value?
2. Is there anyway of defining a type resolver that will manage a whole GraphQL query type instead of per field?
3. Do I need to have a request / response mapping if I am defining the resolver in TS?
4. When returning from the resolver, I keep getting 'unknown' operation. What are the operations that are available? Also, almost all of the examples I find are using DynamoDb. Does this operation only relate to Dynamo? If so, how do I return something (without an operatino) if I am not using Dynamo?
   Any help would be appreciated.